# Automating binary patching in Hopper Disassembler using python

Tags: python, executable, patching, hopper

I am curious to know if anyone has done anything similar to what I am looking to achieve...

1. I have a .ipa file (iOS application) that I load into to Hopper Disassembler.
2. I search for a string to prompt me to a location that I traverse to patch.
3. Patch the instruction as needed.
4. Recompile and create a new executable.

Coding this isn't what I am struggling with. Finding *what* tools to use is. I am pretty experienced with Python, but am open to using any language to patch and create a new executable automatically. Has anyone automated a workflow like this before? I know this stack exchange should be more geared towards specific reverse engineering questions, but I figured this might be the best place to post my question. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.